# Extend element in new list while iterate list in python

Tags: python, list, loops

I have a list of corpus,

```
corpus = ["I want to watch movie. I like it.", "Lets watch this movie together."]
```

First, I want to iterate the 'corpus' list, call one function named createtok and extend all the elements into a new list. After that, I want to reuse both all the element in my new list and all the element called by the previous function for each element in 'corpus' list.

Here is my code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
totaltok = []

corpus = ["I want to watch movie. I like it.", "Lets watch this movie together."]  

for corpuslist in corpus:
    tok = createtok(corpuslist)

    totaltok.extend(tok)

for corpuslist in corpus:

    tok = createtok(corpuslist)
    vtok = generate_v(corpus, tok, totaltok)

    print ("{0}\n{1}\n".format(tok,vtok))
```

May I know, is there any way to simplify this code?

Answer (score 2):

I mean your solution is pretty clear. You can use all the python magic to write less code, but it won't make it more readable.

Take this example - sure, it's slightly lighter, but give this to a junior (and maybe even a mid-level dev, and watch them glaze over)

```
totaltok = list(map(lambda x: createtok(x), corpus))

for tok in map(lambda x: createtok(x), corpus):
    vtok = generate_v(corpus, tok, totaltok)
    print("{0}\n{1}\n".format(tok, vtok))
```

Stick to clarity

Comment: seems like i am the one who glaze over. lol. 
btw totaltok = list(map(lambda x: createtok(x), corpus))  instead of expanding the list, it created two elements in totaltok and the rest work well.

Comment: Did you have any other questions about what you can do?